# can every async/await expression is asynchronous in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have some basic understanding about asyncio concepts in python, but yesterday I played around with it a little bit and now I am confused:

First snippet is obviously asynchronous:

```py
#snippet 1
import asyncio


async def one():
    asyncio.create_task(two())
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('one done')

async def two():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print('two done')

asyncio.run(one())
```

output:

```
two done
one done
```

But with snippet 2 I am not sure (it has the same output as snippet 3):

```py
#snippet2
import asyncio

async def one():
    await asyncio.sleep(3)
    print('one done')

async def two():
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    print('two done')


async def main():
    await one()
    await two()

asyncio.run(main())
```

```py
#snippet3

import time

def one():
    time.sleep(3)
    print('one done')

def two():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    print('two done')

def main():
    one()
    two()

main()
```

output:

```
one done
two done
```

I know that coroutines acts in "non-blocking way", but what it really means if snippet 2 and 3 took the same execution time and have the same output order. Are there advantages of using asyncio without methods like create_task, run_in_executor etc.?

Comment: What things are called is irrelavent

Comment: Snippet 2 is not asynchronous. I don't believe that coroutines do act in a "non-blocking" way. If you replaced the body of main with `await asyncio.gather(one(), two())` then you would be back to having async behaviour. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently for more.

Answer (score 1):

So, asyncio is asynchronous, but, as you observed, just using `await` won't make that code run in parallel. It just means that at that point in the code (where the await, or similar keyword is), the asyncio loop will be able to switch away from your code and run other pending tasks.

The idea is to make it easy to write sequential code, which does not have parallel code changing states of attributes and objects in unexpected ways: the only point other code can run is in these "await" places.

When you have things defined, and know what you want to run in parallel, you create a collection of tasks - those will run concurrently. Usually one will have a barrier point in the code where all concurrent tasks should be done (or where some should be done, and you want to add more to be processed) - this is done by using Python 3.11's `TaskGroup` or calls like `asyncio.gather` or `asyncio.wait`.

So, that is another thing to have in mind in your example code above, you have no problem because task `two`, which runs concurrently, will finish earlier than task `one` and `main`: if you put a larger sleep in it than the one used in the remaining code, your asyncio loop will terminate and task two will be canceled due to the lack of this "barrier" call.